# Putting a custom string in "Authorization" header in System.Net.HttpClient

Tags: .net, dotnet-httpclient, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use the `System.Net.HttpClient` class to post a message to Google Cloud Messaging.

Google Cloud Message requires you to include a header called "Authorization", in a format similar to this:

```
key=AIzaSyBxFuZ9IbtGbJHX6F5wdTc1mHnB7i0Lu8D
```

But the `HttpClient` class throws an exception when I try this.

```
string keyString = "key=AIzaSyBxFuZ9IbtGbJHX6F5wdTc1mHnB7i0LJ0w";
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Foo", keyString); // <== Proving I can
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", keyString); // Exception thrown
```

The exception is of type `System.FormatException`. The message is

> The format of value 'key=AIzaSyBxFuZ9IbtGbJHX6F5wdTc1mHnB7i0LJ0w' is
>   invalid.

And the callstack is:

```
at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaderParser.ParseValue(String value, Object storeValue, Int32& index)
at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.ParseAndAddValue(String name, HeaderStoreItemInfo info, String value)
at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.Add(String name, String value)
```

How can I get this header into this post request without an exception being thrown?

---

Incidentally, I have composed a post like this using Fiddler, and it works:

Headers:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Authorization: key=AIzaSyBxFuZ9IbtGbJHX6F5wdTc1mHnB7i0Lu8D
Host: android.googleapis.com
Content-Length: 220
Content-Type: application/json
```

Request Body:

```
{
 "registration_ids" : ["APA91bEM6XPdiZv5VgNNApakfyYfZwB871018Hljl1L27kaPvksasnR0bHlmcCZFxOSPD6bDLMZgvgfT9xsKnF6Tg0oSQM2cMM1KRbuK7cR7jICqAnSDYg_SvERTzPMT8puXGTlVkEVH6dsneBkXiBu6pZikWXWyRATAVbXnAHTe20-nQerb0"],
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the `Authorization` property on the headers instead of trying to `Add` a new one?

Comment: And also `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("key", "AIzaSyBxFuZ9IbtGbJHX6F5wdTc1mHnB7i0LJ0w");`

Comment: @Joel Allison: I tried that, and then the header was "key AIzaSyBxFuZ9IbtGbJHX6F5wdTc1mHnB7i0LJ0w". It didn't include the '=' sign.

Comment: In case that is your real API key, you might want to revoke it now that you made it public...

Answer (score 7):

Try this answer instead:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24575721/1981387

Seems like a bit of a workaround, since it's a string pair instead of a nice object, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 6):

That's because your value is breaking the HTTP specification.

The header should contain `Authorization: scheme SPACE value` as described here: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt

In your case:

```
Authorization: key AIzaSyBxFuZ9IbtGbJHX6F5wdTc1mHnB7i0Lu8D
```

Comment: It might break the specification, but unfortunately that's what I have to put in to get the Google Cloud Messaging server to accept my message.

Comment: then you need to use the `HttpWebRequest` class instead.

Comment: httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "key=XXX");
See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24575721/143195