# Try to access .Net webservice using HttpClient

Tags: java, c#, .net, httpclient

Below is the example in `.NET C#` language to get resource list for the user

Prepare `HttpRequest` with proper HEADER details

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    // Authorization header value format is "VST {tokenvalue}"
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("VST", securityToken); 
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "text/json");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/json");*
```

Need to write the similar code in Java, I have written the below code in java to access the web-service.

Getting error:

```
HTTP Error 400.
```

The request has an invalid header name.

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(getRequestUrl(baseUrl,   VideologyConstants.GET_CUSTOMERS_API_URL));
request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "VST {" + securityToken + "}");
```

Comment: have you seen that in Java your security header token will be VST { token }? In C# at least I can't see the "{" chars maybe is that?

Comment: // Authorization header value format is "VST {tokenvalue}"

Comment: Try to debug your full request, because the only header is that. It must be a little error there

Comment: Error: Bad Request - Invalid Header..    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("VST", securityToken);--> .NET C# Code. Need to write similar line of code in java.

Comment: try httpGet.setHeader("VST",{token});

Comment: I tried it but getting the below error: {"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}

Comment: now your header is correct. Just debug and be sure that the token format is correct ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("VST", securityToken);

Will produce this header value

Authorization: VST {securityToken}

The way that you can add that header in java is.

```
httpGet.setHeader("Authorization","VST "+token)
```

Here you can check the java API http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/index.html

Comment: Tried and setting the correct header in the HttpGet Method but getting the same error. .Net C# code is using AuthenticationHeaderValue class to set security token.. may be it works in different way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039450/adding-authorization-to-the-headers. it is working now.. Thanks acostela                                                     httpGet.setHeader("Authorization","VST "+token);

Comment: oh you're welcome. I will edit the answer so it fits with your final solution