# Authorization using HttpClient C#

Tags: c#, .net, http

I want to make a program to receive a weather forecast (I use the meteomatics API), but when sending a request to the server it asks for authorization [simple authorization, login and password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGMmj.png) just started learning this field and I don’t know how to solve this problem, I will be glad to get help

I tried to find a solution, but I only found authorization on a separate page, and not in such a pop-up window.

Comment: That looks like a browser-based dialog for HTTP Basic Authentication - in which case do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58014360/how-do-you-use-basic-authentication-with-system-net-http-httpclient

Comment: Start with reading the web API documentation. Particularly, about what kind of authentication information they expect. I highly doubt about a web API expecting basic auth.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible to make an HTTP request using Basic Authentication (even though it is not the most secure).

The "Basic Auth" option is available if you use an API Client. Choosing that will let you enter a username and a password that will be sent along with your request.

[image: Basic Auth option in Insomnia]

As you can see in the image above, using [Insomnnia](https://insomnia.rest/products/insomnia), I can choose Basic Auth. This will let me enter a username and password:
[image: Basic Auth username and password in Insomnia]

If you want to see how this request is translated, you can right-click on the request and choose "Copy as cURL" like so:
[image: Copy as cURL in Insomnia]

If you past it in a text editor, you get the following:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url https://anapi.com/ \
  --header 'Authorization: Basic dGVzdEBkb21haW4uY29tOkFwYXNzd29yZA==' \
  --header 'User-Agent: insomnia/2023.5.8'
```

You can notice that the username and the password have been sent and encoded along with the request.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242316/what-encoding-should-i-use-for-http-basic-authentication) might help you with how the credentials should be encoded.

To finish, as mentioned by @n0rd, start by reading the API documentation. They should mention how the API is expecting your credentials to be sent.

Comment: _"(even though it is not the most secure"_ - Basic Auth isn't insecure when using TLS - and it's no less insecure than Bearer tokens (like JWT) for headless clients and machine-to-machine comms.